# Why @JoinTable(name="user_role") not allowing multiple user_id with role_id

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

Am using springboot with hibernate,

My Entity classes looks like below :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_user")
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    @Column(name="user_Id")
    private long userId;

    @Column(name="userName")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="passWord")
    private String passWord;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="user_role")

 private Collection<Role> roleList;
```

My second entity looks like below :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_role")
public class Role {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="role_Id")
    private long roleId;

    @Column(name="roleName")
    private String roleName;
```

When I insert first user with role as `manager(pkid=1), admin(pkid=2)` its success but while I tried to insert 2nd user with role as `Manager*pkid=1, admin(pkid=2, serviceUser(pkid=3)` it's not allowing me to insert second user with below exception

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'UK_ixctfj5iq0enl7iktlpo7wxct'

Can somebody help me why this constraint is getting creating while generating tables, how can i insert 2nd user into DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `OnetoMany` on `role_list` you are effectively saying that a single `User` will point to many `Roles` and that a `Role` will point to only one `User`. This will be enforced with a `unique` key constraint placed on the `join table`. If you have the SQL statements printed out you will see it when the `schema` is created. Something along the lines of:

```
alter table user_role add constraint UK_ixctfj5iq0enl7iktlpo7wxct unique (role_id)
```

In your requirement, you also have a single `Role` used by many `Users`. Your admin role `primary key` is 2 and you want to be able to assign it to more than one user. Your relationship is a `ManyToMany` for the role_list.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="user_role")
private Collection<Role> roleList;
```

When you change the annotation, you will still have a `join table`, but no constraint will be added.

Comment: Thank you very much Nicholas, you helped me lot !!